# Did Obama make any statements on the OPM breach?

Tags: united-states, china, barack-obama

From Wikipedia's page on [Office of Personnel Management data breach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_of_Personnel_Management_data_breach)
:

> In June 2015, the United States Office of Personnel Management (OPM) announced that it had been the target of a data breach targeting the records of as many as four million people. The final estimate of the number of stolen records is approximately 21.5 million. This includes records of people who had undergone background checks, but who were not necessarily current or former government employees. It has been described by federal officials as among the largest breaches of government data in the history of the United States. Information targeted in the breach included personally identifiable information such as Social Security numbers, as well as names, dates and places of birth, and addresses. [...]
>
> In the aftermath of the event, Katherine Archuleta, the director of OPM, and the CIO, Donna Seymour, resigned.
>
> On August 27, 2017, the FBI arrested a Chinese national suspected of helping to create the malware used in the breach. [...]
>
> President-elect Donald Trump said: "China, relatively recently, hacked 20 million government names. How come nobody even talks about that?"

Did Obama or his spokeperson(s) say anything about the OPM breach?

Comment: _"Did Obama himself or his spokeperson(s) say nothing about the OPM breach?"_ The OPM is an administrative agency within the Executive Branch; the agency itself made public statements about the breach [Cybersecurity Resource Center](https://www.opm.gov/cybersecurity/) _"Approximately 21.5 million individuals were impacted by the cyber incident involving background investigation records OPM announced in 2015. Approximately 4.2 million individuals were impacted by the separate but related cyber incident involving personnel records OPM announced in 2015."_

Comment: Not sure why you limited this to statements.  Talk is cheap, whiskey costs money.

Comment: It's not like the US is going to admit doing something like that in China. Even though it probably has the capabilities (cf. Snowden's leaks and more recently https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/ etc.)

Comment: @guest271314: I meant his own spokesperson(s), not those of agencies. The presidency surely has that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_Press_Secretary I any case, that is moot now since it turned out Obama said something himself.

Answer (score 2):

[A BBC article from September 2015](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-34229439) notes:

> US President Barack Obama has said that alleged Chinese cyber attacks are "not acceptable", ahead of a visit from Chinese leader Xi Jinping.
>
> Several hacks on US institutions have been blamed on China, including one involving millions of government staff.
>
> Mr Obama said the US needed to be more rapid in its response to such attacks.
>
> [...]
>
> Mr Obama made his remarks after meeting members of the US military at Fort Meade, Maryland, with Mr Xi due in Washington later this month.
>
> "We have been very clear to the Chinese that there are certain practices that they are engaging in, that we know are emanating from China and are not acceptable."
>
> He suggested the two sides would have to agree on common rules in cyberspace, arguing "there comes a point at which we consider this a core national security threat and we will treat it as such".
>
> But he said that China should fear confrontation online: "I guarantee you we will win if we have to."

Comment: So that's two countries he said Cut It Out to no effect whatsoever.

Comment: "Now go away, or I shall taunt you a second time!"

Comment: Unfortunately in politics saying something is worth 10 times as much as actions. As we are finding out right now. Examining it clinically, politics is about emotion over logic and the low information constituents are happier with that.  Welcome to Idiocracy.